# Import and Exporting users from an Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

I'm trying to move a SharePoint site from one server to another.  I'm supposed to move all the users with their permissions as well.  I've been told that the best way to do that is to export the users from the AD and then import the list on the target server.

Is this the best way to accomplish this?  How do I export only the users and permissions and then import them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't move an active directory with user and their permissions unless the servers you are moving it between are networked.  You can then change server roles and move the directory that way.  A more thorough example can be found [here](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/39959/how-can-i-move-the-active-directory-ad-global-catalog-gc-to-another-domain-controller-dc.html).  Since there weren't too many users in the AD in the first place, I ended up manually adding them myself.

Answer (score 0):

The purist answer is to use stsadm export operation with the includeusersecurity option. Personally I'm not an stsadm fan and would recommend you use the [SP Deployment Wizard](http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard) tool and make sure you select the User info update to import all. That will bring in the security + user information for their profile.